# Migrate multiple IP of multiple servers to another network

Tags: linux, windows

What's the best way to execute this task:
We have 100servers with IPs 172.16.1.0/24. (static IP address)
All of the server's IPs need to be moved to 172.16.2.0/24 network.
50servers-linux
50servers-windows

Assuming this is a lab environment without other things(DNS,application,etc) to consider. What's the best way to do this efficiently?

Comment: yes. since they are servers they're assigned static ip addresses

Answer (score 1):

Either shut the whole thing down and do it by hand all in one go or;

1. Setup and test routing between both networks, ensure all current firewall and load-balancing configs take the changes into account (i.e. matching FW rules, VIP groups include the new IPs).
2. Ensure your DNS server has IPs on both networks.
3. Choose a low-impact server, update its DNS entries, throw over its IP, DG, DNS server and any other settings. For Windows it may be prudent to unregister Windows servers from AD and then register them again once moved, depends on versions.
4. Test this server and if ok move on to the next one, repeat until finished.
5. Tidy up your router/s, FW/s, LB/s

You've not given us much (anything) to go on but there is a potential third way if every server is on one VLAN, which would be to switch everything to using a /23 NM then just update DNS and move the IPs one at a time. I'm not a fan of this approach and you'd have to switch everything back to a /24 at the end and tidy but I thought I'd mention it.

Personally for such a small estate I'd just get a nice wide outage window and do them all at once.

Comment: Hi Chopper, thank you for attending to my query.
Actually, I didn't give any details like DNS,FW rules, etc because my only right concern is changing the IPs. I'm only thinking of using an automation tool like Puppet. But are there other ways? like creating a bash script, etc..

Comment: You'd still need to take all those other things into account and given how few servers you have and the risk of a script killing your environment I'd still be tempted to do it by hand.

Comment: Yes, but for now it's just a theoretical question to make things simpler. For production, I'll really consider those things you've mentioned.

Answer (score -3):

I would set them all up to use DHCP and "fixed addreses" rather than "static addresses". This can be done with no downtime. (this likely means you need 2 DHCP servers, one per network; and if you depend on DHCP, you need to make sure you have more than one DHCP server per network (redundant), and they are reliable)

Then I would change the dhcp settings (change fixed addresses) and move the servers physically if needed. Then I would get them to query the DHCP server again.

Regardless of what tool you use to configure them (eg. set them to DHCP, restart network), DHCP lets you control the configuration centrally.

Personally, I just use DHCP on netboot server and cluster nodes. The others are static. If I had more than 100 though, they would be mostly DHCP (eg. my routers, dns, and dhcp servers would remain static). I'm not sure what opinions others have on whether they would put regular enterprise servers on DHCP fixed addresses. (please comment if so, because I would be very interested to hear it)

Comment: Hello Peter, welcome to SF. You won't know this as you're new but the subject of using DHCP for servers in a professional environment has been discussed to *death* on this site with the very strong opinion by the vast majority of pro sysadmins here that it's one of the single worst ideas ever conceived. The main issue being that a single rogue DHCP server/device can take down your entire environment. As such I can not only not recommend your approach but actively warn this user against your response. Sorry, nothing personal.

Comment: Agree with @Chopper3 on this one. This is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I'm not perfectly convinced that in all cases it is a huge problem. The chance of someone sneaking in a rogue DHCP server just to mess up your network seems to be limited to certain types of networks (eg. the LAN with all your workstations, some fileservers, etc.). And I haven't explored all the options in managed switches, but don't they have several features to limit such traffic to specific ports (DHCP Snooping)?

Comment: And so I guess what I should ask is: please point me to something discrediting DHCP snooping (even if it is just about complexity), or do you think I should just edit and  point it out in my answer above?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I edited my question. The servers are all in static IP, now the goal is to move all of them to another network. Assuming this is a lab environment, no other things to consider. What's the best way to do this?